# Python import statement is not working for parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.9.5.

Based on [this post](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-import-from-parent-directory/), I'm trying to reuse some functions from the parent directory. Here's my code hierarchy:

```
github_repository
    src
        base
            string_utilities.py
        validation
            email_validator.py
```

I also have `__init__.py` in all folders. In ALL of them.

Here's the `string_utilities.py` content:

```
def isNullOrEmpty(text: str):
    return text is not None and len(text) > 0
```

And here's the `email_validator.py` content:

```
from src.base import string_utilities

def is_email(text: str):
    if string_utilities.isNullOrEmpty(text):
        return False
    # logic to check email
    return True
```

Now when I run `python email_validator.py`, I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

I have changed that frustrating import statement to all of these different forms, and I still get no results:

```
from ...src.base import string_utilities
```

which results in:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

```
import src.base.string_utilities
```

Which causes compiler to not know the `isNullOrEmpty` function.

```
import ...src.base.string_utilities
```

Which results in:

> Relative imports cannot be used with "import .a" form; use "from . import a" instead

I'm stuck at this point on how to reuse that function in this file. Can someone please help?

Comment: run like this `python src/validation/email_validator.py`

Comment: @VishalSingh, ran `python src\validation\email_validator.py` since I'm on Windows, and got the same error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

Comment: Try printing the sys.path and check if your modules are getting listed. if your module is not getting listed try adding them in either PYTHONPATH or using sys.path.insert

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py BrenBarn's answer might hold the explanation to build some knowledge here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3/28154841#28154841 explanation I found browsing the above mentioned post

Comment: @heretolearn, thanks for that note. I printed `sys.path` and only the `validation` package is listed. But I read in many places that placing `__init__.py` file in parent directories, automatically registers them as packages. That's weird.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli, yes ideally if you add __init__.py, that tells the interpreter that the directory is a python directory. Can you put the exact directory structure including the inits. Also can you try adding the root path to the PYTHONPATH ?